# Nth occurrence of day of week for NEXT month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula to calculate the Nth occurrence of the specified day of the week, BUT if that date is past, I want to know the Nth occurrence in the NEXT month.

I'm using this to get the Nth day:

```
=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1+7*A)-
  WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),8-B))
```

A= Nth occurrence of day of week
B= day of week

So above, if A=1 and B=4, I'd get first Wed. But if today's date is past the first Wed of the current month, I need the first Wed of the following month.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an IF with your formula as the condition, then add +1 to month part of the DATE when the result is less than NOW():

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1+7*A)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),8-B))<NOW(),DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())+1,1+7*A)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())+1,8-B)),DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1+7*A)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),8-B)))
```